# In Jurassic Park, how was there a 100 ft. drop where the T-Rex just came from?

Tags: jurassic-park

When the T-Rex attacks in Jurassic Park, the area on the other side of the fence has low-growing bushes and trees, as well as the spot where the goat was tied. In fact, the T-Rex is clearly seen walking on the ground. However, Dr. Grant escapes by rappelling down the other side of the concrete wall, which has a 100 ft. drop. How did this drop magically appear? In the wide shot you can even see that there's nowhere for the T-Rex to walk.

Comment: Jurassic Park has glaring continuity errors. Chalk it up to bad movie magic.

Comment: The T-Rex is an excellent vertical jumper.

Comment: Why did the T-Rex cross the road?...

Comment: @DVK: so nobody would call it a [chicken](http://xkcd.com/1211/)!

Comment: This and other errors in JP: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KjB-_bjOJs

Comment: Please don't fix errors that don't exist. It's printed as "T-Rex" in the novel. Do not fix this again. Here's a link to the script: http://sfy.ru/?script=jurassic_park

Comment: Related: [How did the T-Rex reach the vehicles in Jurassic Park?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65010/49)

Comment: This particular T-Rex was a slow learner. After eating the goat, he then grabs onto the wire fence which is usually electrified. He must not have cared about getting zapped if he did this everyday.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It may just be a mistake, but a [page on the defunct website jplegacy.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910064744/https://www.jplegacy.org/?ffjpking) tried to find a justification by suggesting that although the ground is level with the wall in most places, in one spot it drops off into a deep ravine or moat, and that's why the fence tapers off there. An excerpt:

> Now, let's look at our film evidence: First we have the initial
>   arrival. We can see here that the fence is quite long. If you look,
>   the fence actually doesn't stretch all the way to the tunnel, instead,
>   it all seems to converge into a small point next the tunnel. This
>   would seemingly be an error-a gratuitous error-if the rex's range
>   stretched all the way to the tunnel and further. This is our first
>   hint that the paddock has a boundary further in.

Here's the picture they give showing where the fence drops off on the left, which would be problematic if the ground was still level there since it seems like the T. Rex could just step over:

[image: T-Rex fence]

[Here is the original script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/jurassicpark_script_final_12_92.html), which has a descriptive paragraph that basically seems to support the idea above:

> the T-rex starts to nudge the Explorer toward the barrier.  Over the barrier, there is a gentle terraced area at one side where the rex emerged from, but the car isn't next to that, it's next to a sharp precipice, representing a fifty or sixty foot drop.

This diagram (source unknown, pulled from comments) shows a plausible arrangement. It's appears to be notated in meters, so "-15,00" matches with "fifty feet".

[image: T-Rex Paddock Diagram]

Comment: ...And this is why zoos make me jumpy.  It's apparently normal practice to do stuff like that.  There's one in particular that has these spiders bigger than my hand and webs that stretch floor to ceiling and several feet across, with absolutely no containment whatsoever - just a small wall to keep guests from getting too close.  They just trust that the spiders won't go anywhere because that's where their webs are and where they get food.

Comment: Hello Izkata. We were long dreaming of meeting you again. Sincerely - Spider friend from the zoo.

Comment: @Izkata Where is this zoo? It's important I know, so I can never go there.

Comment: @MattThrower - It's directly over your bed. Sleep well...

Comment: There's a nice illustration of this idea: http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m8tqn6T4FK1rsiohpo1_1280.jpg

Answer (score 25):

This is something from the book that was not explained in the movie. (well, there was one throw away line that was easily missed) there is a moat between ground level in the T-rex paddock, and the fence. This exists to discourage the dinos from getting close to the fence.

It is this moat that the car is pushed into. There is a section of the book that deals with Grant trying to figure out how to climb out of this moat with Tim and Lex (the T-rex simply steps over it)

> There were only six divisions on the whole island. And each division
>   was separated from the road by a concrete moat.

...

> "You know," Ellie said, "some of these dimensions are enormous. Look at this. This concrete moat is thirty feet wide. That's like a military fortification."

...

> "Absolutely not," Arnold said. "These are expensive animals, Mr. Gennaro.
>   We take very good care of them. We maintain multiple barriers. First, the moats." He pressed a button, and the board lit up with a network of orange bars. "These moats are never less than twelve feet deep, and water-filled. For bigger animals the moats may be thirty feet deep.

Comment: If this is accurate, that the book actually describes a moat, why the downvote. Sure it doesn't answer the question, but it describes crucial information the movie does not, i.e. some context.

Comment: I'm with cde on this. Is there any chance we can get the throwaway line from the film, and possibly a reference from the book.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - Added some book references

Comment: If anyone has the book handy, how'd the T-Rex get over the moat once the power went out? Or did that scene not happen in the book? I read it a while ago but I don't remember.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Just reread the book.  As I recall, it is never explicitly stated how the T-Rex got over the moat in that particular scene.  However, in other scenes, the T-Rex is shown to be able to walk along the bottom of a river, and it is shown it can also swim quite well.  Kind of makes the moats pointless.

Answer (score 13):

This is a [very](http://movieplotholes.com/jurassic-park.html) [well-known](http://www.moviemistakes.com/film690) [continuity error](http://www.buzzfeed.com/briangalindo/15-questions-jurassic-park-left-unanswered). There is abaolutely no in-universe explanation. Unless the T-Rex could fly.

Comment: Axe Cop has a T-Rex that can fly! He also has machine guns for hands.

Comment: @LordSnow: He's also married to Abraham Lincoln. But I don't think he was at Jurassic Park.

Comment: I can absolutely imagine Axe Cop working security at Jurassic Park :-)

Answer (score 1):

The T-Rex snapped several lines of cable when it broke out. But during the scene where it pushed the car off. Grant and Lex are near a gap. That's the security moat to keep the animals in place. But the moat isn't a perfect perimeter, there are parts where the land comes straight up to the fence. That's where the animal escaped.

[image: Map showing where the T-rex escaped through the fence]